# SQL only one cell from column can have X value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to ensure, when you design a table - SQL, MySQL -, that only one cell from column X is `true`, the rest being automatically `false`? When you change the value of a different cell to true, all other cells should automatically become false. A radio button type of exclusivity, but for a column.

```
mainOfferName | value
---------------------
pizza         | false
spaghetti     | false
salad         | true
stew          | false
```

Upon change of pizza as the main offer you'd get something like this:

```
mainOfferName | value
---------------------
pizza         | true
spaghetti     | false
salad         | false
stew          | false
```

I can run the query manually and make sure only one value is true at any given time, but I'm curious if I could put a constrain into my table so that I only change the the row/cell I need to `true` and the DB engine takes care of keeping only that value `true`.

Comment: What would you need this for? I feel like this goes against what you'd use a database for. Perhaps you can create a variable `selectedItem` that points to the row you wanT?

Comment: @McAdam331 Curiosity.

Comment: Fair enough haha. I wasn't advising against it, just curious myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a separate table with one row that contains the `mainOfferName` of the row that you want.  Then query as:

```
select yt.*, (nt.mainOfferName is not null) as valueFlag
from yourtable yt left join
     newtable nt
     on yt.mainOfferName = nt.mainOfferName;
```

When you want to change the value, change the value in `newtable`.

Note:  you can put the query into a view and read-only users will just work.

And, you could implement this with an `update` trigger on `yourtable`.  Instead of updating `yourtable`, it would update `newtable`.

Comment: That's great! Bravo ...!

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thank you.

Comment: have a question. what is mean of `yt.*` ? `yt` is a alias name, but what is `.*` ? when you use `*`, it is mean all and you don't need to use anything else. can you explain me more ? tnx

Comment: @stack the asterisk is used to select all columns. In this case, there is a join so the asterisk will select all columns from both tables. By putting the table alias first, only the columns from that table will be selected.

Comment: I have a question irrelevant to the topic, Is there a difference between these two words? `nt.mainOfferName is not null` and `nt.mainOfferName <>''`

Comment: @stack . . . Yes.  The first checks that the column is not `NULL`.  The second checks that the column is neither `NULL` nor the empty string.

Comment: Thanks for answered and I am ashamed to ask again, But really I like to know. I think `NULL` and empty string are the same, is it not ? Can you show me a example that be `NULL` but not empty string ? Or vice versa.